# sending a data to another activity with putExtra and doesn't work java android

Tags: java, android, xml

I used intent to send a primarykey of my app to another activity but it debug my application I don't know why?
I'm sure that I put the syntax corrrectly and I tried many way I used bundle object but the same result the application has stopped

Activity iden_espvol

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(iden_espvol.this,verf_tel_espvol.class);
               intent.putExtra("TEL",tel.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                 finish();
```

Activity  verf_tel_espvol

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  String sent=intent.getStringExtra("TEL");
```

Comment: post your error log.

Comment: First of all if you are coding in java then follow naming convention of Java. And to answer your code seems incomplete.

Comment: You might want to consider looking in the Logcat error message thay you get when your app crashes (on the bottom of Android Studio window). It will help you find where is the problem). If you don't understand details of the exception stack trace that shows up in Logcat, edit your question and include stack trace here. By the way, are you sure that `tel` is not `null` when calling `getText()` on it?

Comment: I'm sure that tel is not null cause it sent data to firebase realtime data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.. and i hope you define both activity in manifest file..

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(LayoutActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("TEL","65421321");
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

and in second activity onCreate() method

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
    String sent=intent.getStringExtra("TEL");
    Log.d("Data",sent);
```

make sure value get only oncreate or onResume method because first activity finished that time call second activity this method.

Comment: it works I did a  mistake I write the second code  in class before oncreate method anyway thank you

Comment: How about sending extra with name "string"?